# Android Start activity without creating new instance

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-manifest

Assume i have activity A that act as the root activity for my app . and form this activity i go to activity B.

I want to be able to go back from B to A Without creating new instance of Activity A.

this code is in Activity B

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
//      Intent intent= new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
//      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        Log.d("Back", "TEST");
    }
```

but it sill call the onCreate on activity A . What i want to do is have A in the background when activity b is started and whenever it is finished switch back to activity A

this is the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:stateNotNeeded="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SubmenuActivty" >
        </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for whoever rated this down . did you even read ?

Answer (score 12):

***According to android activity life cycle, when you launch an activity A :***

Life Cycle method list :

```
Activity A.onResume();
Activity A.onStart();
Activity A.onCreate();
```

Activity Status :

```
Activity A : Resumed
```

***When you launch the activity B now :***

Life Cycle method list :

```
Activity A.onStop();  
Activity B.onResume();
Activity B.onStart();
Activity B.onCreate();
Activity A.onPause();
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Activity Status :

```
   Activity A : Stopped
   Activity B : Resumed
```

***And when you again start A now :***

Life Cycle method list :

```
Activity B.onDestroy();  
Activity B.onStop(); 
Activity A.onResume();
  ....
  ....
  ....
```

Activity Status :

```
   Activity B : Destroyed
   Activity A : Resumed
```

This is the life cycle of an activity :
[image]

You can find the details [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

According to default behavior, activity A goes to onStop() state and doesn't alive and need to create a new instance on coming back to activity A. All I know - there is no way to keep alive of the A instance.

Comment: When A starts B, A is just stopped (but still **alive**). As soon as B finishes it will automatically restart and resume A. A will be alive until it calls `finish()` on itself.

Answer (score 5):

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Try it... It makes old activity to front without new instance...

Answer (score 2):

You Dont need do anything. Just remove your `onBackPressed()` method from Activity B.

By default when you move from *Activity A* to *Activity B*, Android adds the *Activity A* to the backstack. When you press the back button from *Activity B* or finish it, it automatically restore the Activity A from backstack.

If you wish to finish your Activity B programmatically call activity's `finish()` method when you want to do it.

Comment: it will restore Activity a from the backstack by creating new instance of the it. i want to have Activity A alive all the time

Comment: do u finish Activity A while starting Activity B? If not surely Activity A will get restored to its last state from backstack

Comment: i dont i use Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SubmenuActivty.class);startActivity(myIntent); to start activity A

Comment: did u tried removing your onBackPressed() method from Activity B?

Comment: What do you mean by "want to have Activity A alive all the time"? It is alive, it is just hidden by Activity B. Please define "alive". What is it that you want Activity A to do when Activity B is completely covering it and getting all user input?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.d("Back", "TEST");
}
```

And thats all, what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use     moveTaskToBack(true);

```
public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
moveTaskToBack(true); 
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

or You can also use finish()

Comment: this doesn't keep activity alive it will just create new instance of the activity .. it will call the oncreate method again

Answer (score 0):

Why you start an activity in `onBackPressed` anyway?
You should `super.onBackPressed();` instead of starting new activity. Or call `finish()` method in you `onBackPressed()` method:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        Log.d("Back", "TEST");
    }
```